# intents in my discord bot does not seems to work

Tags: python, discord, pycharm

i just move to a new pc and copied all the script from my bot. The thing is that i cant make it work since or i get this error:

discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal.

Or it does not seems to get his intents right.

For me they can all be enable as it was or something, already checked the developer site and the boxes are checked.

this is the bit where the intents are:

```
import discord
import re
import json
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import sqlite3

prefix = "*" 

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```